# Change TabBar Appearance

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to change tabView appearance with new swiftui framework. I tried this :

```
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)!]
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.TabViewItemNormalColor.uiColor()]

appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)!]
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.TabViewItemNormalColor.uiColor()]
```

But only text color changed, font stayed the same as previous

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)!,
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.TabViewItemNormalColor.uiColor()
]

appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes =  [
    NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)!, 
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: Color.TabViewItemNormalColor.uiColor()
]
```